# How to fix install openvpn on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos

All image about my problem is [here](https://imgur.com/a/mVj4i)

Why I can't install openvpn with `yum` even I try to fix it like [this](http://www.drmagu.com/openvpn-introduction-and-installation-on-centos-432.htm) website said  . What is wrong in here? Help me, please people. By the way, the problem I see,is package not exit on mirror website. So which mirror have openvpn?

Answer (score 3):

You simply have to install the `epel` repository: `yum -y install epel-release` to make the `openvpn` package available.

Comment: what do you said about this: http://imgur.com/a/QloAZ. ? this is my problem after try like Julie said.

Comment: If my answer was good, can you click the checkmark on the left to chose my answer?

Comment: @JuliePelletier if you change it from `epel-repository` to `epel-release`, your answer would be correct.

Comment: @jsbillings: Thanks for that fine observation.  I've corrected it.